# If I start a new StarCraft 2 campaign can I still watch the movies from my completed campaign?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've completed the campaign and would like to be able to periodically re-watch some of the movies. Is there a way to do so if I start a new campaign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just save in  different file and just load your old save file to watch the movies. Or search in youtube :P

Comment: I was hoping another answer would show up, but this doesn't appear to be the case. Pretty lame user-experience but at this time this is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise, you could get the MPQ Editor, extract the movies and watch them in a separate video player. It works great for Warcraft 3 too.

Comment: I imagine the YouTube route might be a bit simpler if you don't plan to use the in-game interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you have completed the campaign and start a new campaign you will always be able to click the continue campaign button and get access to the complete list of games and movies the times you have completed the missions on different dificulties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. On the ship in the the room with space map you will have a terminal with all missions archived. There you will be able to watch any movie

Comment: Missions/movies that have been completed within that save are shown. If he starts a new game, then movies and missions from the original save will not show up.